# Prevent child button triggering a jquery event assigned to a parent

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to prevent a button inside a table row triggering the event attached to the row

This solution works, but I don't like it:

```
$('table.orders tr.item').live('click',function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('hrf');
    document.location.href = id;
});
$('table.orders tr.item .pdfIcon').live('click',function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I don't like the idea of having a 2nd event attached to prevent the first from working. I should be able to remove it from the selection.

Can anyone suggest a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('table.orders').on('click', 'tr.item', function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).hasClass('pdfIcon')){
        var id=$(this).attr('hrf');
        document.location.href = id;
    }
});
```

Comment: I just read the JQuery docs for on(). Should I be using on() rather than live? Is it a better option? Will it act the same way as live()?

Comment: Yes - `live` has been deprecated in favor of `on`. Syntactic sugar aside, there's a big performance gain: `live` bubbles the event all the way up the DOM to `body`, whereas `on` only allows the event to go as far up as the element it was called on.

Comment: `live` was also removed in the 1.9 release.

Comment: This code didn't actually work due to 2 small mistakes, the . before pdfIcon and the missing { after it. It's working fine now I've made those changes. I've also edited the answer you provided. Thanks for your help. Also a big thanks about the heads up about the removal of live() from 1.9 - I was just about to update to it. Looks like I've got a bit of code editing to do!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$('table.orders tr.item').live('click',function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is('.pdfIcon')) return;
    var id=$(this).attr('hrf');
    document.location.href = id;
});
```

Comment: wouldn't `if ($(e.target).is('.pdfIcon')) return;` be enough

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('table.orders').on('click', 'tr.item', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('pdfIcon')) {
        return;
    }
    var id = $(this).attr('hrf');
    document.location.href = id;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qxLvY/)

Comment: This is essentially the same as @ethagnawl previous answer. It does work btw :-)

Comment: I did enjoy the demo though!